# how do I output my code to a single file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, printing

I need to dump all of my code for my project into a single text file. Is this possible in Visual Studio 2010? I haven't been able to find any options for this in VS. Is there a third party program that can do it? Every search I've done just turns up "how to print from VB", but does not address printing my actual code. Even if I have to do it module by module, that would be acceptable, but copying and pasting is a bit much.

Just FYI, I'm not talking about printing output from my program. I'm talking about printing the program itself.

Thanks.

Comment: You could write a program to do that...

Comment: or... I could do what MarkL suggests below and be finished in about 5 minutes ;) .

Comment: Please be aware that if a .vb file doesn't end with a CRLF then you can end up with lines like `End ClassImports System.Web.Services`, you don't get the filenames in the file, and `type` doesn't go into subdirectories (you might have a subfolder for class files, for example). But if MarkL's solution works for you, that's good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done outside of visual studio.  Start a command prompt, cd to your project directory and:

```
type *.vb >filecontent.txt
```

If you have multiple project folders, you'll need to do this for each one as the type command doesn't have a /s subfolder type of parameter.

Alternatively, you could create a batch file that changes to each folder and performs the type command to output the file contents.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know .vb files were stored as plain text.